# MySQL Workbench cannot add foreign key constraint

Tags: mysql, sql, database, key, constraints

My SQL script works fine, till some point where error 1215 appears. I don't know what is wrong whith the code.

Here's the code:

```
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS ΝΟΣΟΚΟΜΕΙΟ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ΤΜΗΜΑΤΑ
(ΚΩΔΙΚΟΣ_ΤΜΗΜΑΤΟΣ INT,
 ΟΝΟΜΑΣΙΑ_ΤΜΗΜΑΤΟΣ CHAR, 
ΣΥΝΟΛΙΚΟΣ_ΑΡΙΘΜΟΣ_ΚΛΙΝΩΝ INT,
 ΔΙΑΘΕΣΙΜΟΣ_ΑΡΙΘΜΟΣ_ΚΛΙΝΩΝ INT,
PRIMARY KEY (ΚΩΔΙΚΟΣ_ΤΜΗΜΑΤΟΣ));

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ΑΣΘΕΝΕΙΣ
(ΚΩΔΙΚΟΣ_ΑΣΘΕΝΗ INT,
 ΟΝΟΜΑ_ΑΣΘΕΝΗ VARCHAR (20), 
ΕΠΩΝΥΜΟ_ΑΣΘΕΝΗ VARCHAR (20),
 ΦΥΛΛΟ VARCHAR (1), 
ΗΜ_ΝΙΑ_ΓΕΝΝΗΣΗΣ DATE,
 ΔΙΕΥΘΥΝΣΗ_ΑΣΘΕΝΗ CHAR ,
 ΤΗΛΕΦΩΝΟ_ΑΣΘΕΝΗ VARCHAR (10),
PRIMARY KEY (ΚΩΔΙΚΟΣ_ΑΣΘΕΝΗ));

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ΙΑΤΡΟΙ
(ΚΩΔΙΚΟΣ_ΙΑΤΡΟΥ INT ,
 ΟΝΟΜΑ_ΙΑΤΡΟΥ VARCHAR (20),
 ΕΠΩΝΥΜΟ_ΙΑΤΡΟΥ VARCHAR (20),
 ΕΙΔΙΚΟΤΗΤΑ CHAR,
ΚΩΔΙΚΟΣ_ΤΜΗΜΑΤΟΣ INT,
 ΔΙΕΥΘΥΝΣΗ_ΙΑΤΡΟΥ CHAR,
 ΤΗΛΕΦΩΝΟ_ΙΑΤΡΟΥ VARCHAR (10),
PRIMARY KEY (ΚΩΔΙΚΟΣ_ΙΑΤΡΟΥ),
FOREIGN KEY (ΚΩΔΙΚΟΣ_ΤΜΗΜΑΤΟΣ) REFERENCES ΤΜΗΜΑΤΑ(ΚΩΔΙΚΟΣ_ΤΜΗΜΑΤΟΣ)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ΠΕΡΙΣΤΑΤΙΚΑ
(ΚΩΔΙΚΟΣ_ΠΕΡΙΣΤΑΤΙΚΟΥ INT, 
ΚΩΔΙΚΟΣ_ΑΣΘΕΝΗ INT, 
ΚΩΔΙΚΟΣ_ΤΜΗΜΑΤΟΣ INT,
ΚΩΔΙΚΟΣ_ΙΑΤΡΟΥ INT, 
ΗΜ_ΝΙΑ_ΕΙΣΑΓΩΓΗΣ DATE, 
ΗΜ_ΝΙΑ_ΕΞΙΤΗΡΙΟΥ DATE,
 ΑΞΙΑ_ΠΕΡΙΣΤΑΤΙΚΟΥ INT,
PRIMARY KEY (ΚΩΔΙΚΟΣ_ΠΕΡΙΣΤΑΤΙΚΟΥ),
FOREIGN KEY (ΚΩΔΙΚΟΣ_ΑΣΘΕΝΗ) REFERENCES ασθενεισ(ΚΩΔΙΚΟΣ_ΑΣΘΕΝΗ),
FOREIGN KEY (ΚΩΔΙΚΟΣ_ΤΜΗΜΑΤΟΣ) REFERENCES τμηματα(ΚΩΔΙΚΟΣ_ΤΜΗΜΑΤΟΣ),
FOREIGN KEY (ΚΩΔΙΚΟΣ_ΙΑΤΡΟΥ) REFERENCES ιατροι(ΚΩΔΙΚΟΣ_ΙΑΤΡΟΥ)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ΚΑΤΗΓΟΡΙΕΣ_ΠΡΟΪΟΝΤΩΝ
(ΚΩΔΙΚΟΣ_ΚΑΤΗΓΟΡΙΑΣ INT,
ΟΝΟΜΑΣΙΑ_ΚΑΤΗΓΟΡΙΑΣ CHAR,
PRIMARY KEY (ΚΩΔΙΚΟΣ_ΚΑΤΗΓΟΡΙΑΣ)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ΠΡΟΪΟΝΤΑ
(ΚΩΔΙΚΟΣ_ΠΡΟΪΟΝΤΟΣ INT,
 ΚΩΔΙΚΟΣ_ΚΑΤΗΓΟΡΙΑΣ INT,
 ΟΝΟΜΑΣΙΑ_ΠΡΟΪΟΝΤΟΣ CHAR,
 ΑΞΙΑ_ΜΟΝΑΔΑΣ_ΠΡΟΪΟΝΤΟΣ INT,
PRIMARY KEY (ΚΩΔΙΚΟΣ_ΠΡΟΪΟΝΤΟΣ),
FOREIGN KEY (ΚΩΔΙΚΟΣ_ΚΑΤΗΓΟΡΙΑΣ) REFERENCES ΚΑΤΗΓΟΡΙΕΣ_ΠΡΟΪΟΝΤΩΝ(ΚΩΔΙΚΟΣ_ΚΑΤΗΓΟΡΙΑΣ)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ΧΡΕΩΣΕΙΣ_ΠΕΡΙΣΤΑΤΙΚΩΝ
(ΚΩΔΙΚΟΣ_ΠΕΡΙΣΤΑΤΙΚΟΥ  INT,
ΚΩΔΙΚΟΣ_ΠΡΟΪΟΝΤΟΣ  INT,
 ΗΜΕΡΟΜΗΝΙΑ_ΧΡΕΩΣΗΣ DATE,
 ΠΟΣΟΤΗΤΑ INT,
PRIMARY KEY (ΗΜΕΡΟΜΗΝΙΑ_ΧΡΕΩΣΗΣ),
FOREIGN KEY (ΚΩΔΙΚΟΣ_ΠΕΡΙΣΤΑΤΙΚΟΥ) REFERENCES ΠΕΡΙΣΤΑΤΙΚΑ(ΚΩΔΙΚΟΣ_ΠΕΡΙΣΤΑΤΙΚΟΥ),
FOREIGN KEY (ΚΩΔΙΚΟΣ_ΠΡΟΪΟΝΤΟΣ) REFERENCES ΠΡΟΙΟΝΤΑ(ΚΩΔΙΚΟΣ_ΠΡΟΪΟΝΤΟΣ)
);
```

...........................................

I have a problem with the last two tables where that error occurs.Is there anyone that could help me ?

Thanks, Dimitris

Comment: Table names may be case-sensitive by default. In table ΠΕΡΙΣΤΑΤΙΚΑ, you reference tables in lower-case like ασθενεισ, but earlier you defined the tables in upper-case like ΑΣΘΕΝΕΙΣ. Try it again with the table name references in the same case: ΑΣΘΕΝΕΙΣ.

Comment: The second error defining ΧΡΕΩΣΕΙΣ_ΠΕΡΙΣΤΑΤΙΚΩΝ is simply because the first table ΠΕΡΙΣΤΑΤΙΚΑ failed to be created.

Comment: The lower-case is not really a problem although I changed it, because when it creates the tables all the names are lower-case letters.
ΠΕΡΙΣΤΑΤΙΚΑ is created, but when it comes to ΠΡΟΙΟΝΤΑ it cannot add foreign keys constraint. And if I delete both the foreign keys then ΧΡΕΩΣΕΙΣ_ΠΕΡΙΣΤΑΤΙΚΩΝ does the same :/
ΚΑΤΗΓΟΡΙΕΣ_ΠΡΟΪΟΝΤΩΝ is also created but for some reason ...error 1215 :P

Answer (score 0):

I tested this on Linux, MySQL 5.6.17. I was able to get this to work with two changes:

1. Match the case of table names to the way they are spelled when you create them:

   ```
   CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ΠΕΡΙΣΤΑΤΙΚΑ
   (
           . . . 
           FOREIGN KEY (ΚΩΔΙΚΟΣ_ΑΣΘΕΝΗ) REFERENCES ΑΣΘΕΝΕΙΣ(ΚΩΔΙΚΟΣ_ΑΣΘΕΝΗ),
           FOREIGN KEY (ΚΩΔΙΚΟΣ_ΤΜΗΜΑΤΟΣ) REFERENCES ΤΜΗΜΑΤΑ(ΚΩΔΙΚΟΣ_ΤΜΗΜΑΤΟΣ),
           FOREIGN KEY (ΚΩΔΙΚΟΣ_ΙΑΤΡΟΥ) REFERENCES ΙΑΤΡΟΙ(ΚΩΔΙΚΟΣ_ΙΑΤΡΟΥ)
   );
   ```
2. Use the same spelling, including diacritics in ΠΡΟΪΟΝΤΑ:

   ```
   CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ΧΡΕΩΣΕΙΣ_ΠΕΡΙΣΤΑΤΙΚΩΝ
   (
           . .  .
           FOREIGN KEY (ΚΩΔΙΚΟΣ_ΠΡΟΪΟΝΤΟΣ) REFERENCES ΠΡΟΪΟΝΤΑ(ΚΩΔΙΚΟΣ_ΠΡΟΪΟΝΤΟΣ)
   );
   ```

Comment: I fixed that but the problem still exists. Foreign keys can't be added for ΠΕΡΙΣΤΑΤΙΚΑ, ΠΡΟΪΟΝΤΑ and ΧΡΕΩΣΕΙΣ_ΠΕΡΙΣΤΑΤΙΚΩΝ tables. I don't have any spell mistake

Comment: You can find out which CREATE TABLE got the error if you run the script with `mysql -v`. Another debugging method is to comment out the foreign key declarations one by one and retry the test, to find out which constraint is failing.